# Metadata xml for creating Replaying Party trust/Claims Provider Trusts

Tags: metadata, adfs, adfs2.0, federation

I am developing a web application for a client and need to implement SSO and he asked me provide "federation metadata xml" as I'm completely new to ADFS I have no idea of what he is expecting. Can someone tell me how to create the metadata xml. It would be really helpful if provide me any code samples.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata describes your endpoints, what protocol you are using, certificate details etc.

For a web application it's easier to create the ADFS entry manually!

There are a number of articles around on the topic of "programmatically generate metadata wif" e.g. [this](http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2013/08/automatically-generate-federation-metadata-for-your-asp-net-application/) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scicoria/2010/08/18/federation-metadata-generation-tool/).